# Deleting a database in a multi-database, single Berkeley DB JE environment

Tags: java, database, scala, berkeley-db-je

I have a coupled *main* and a (temporary and *auxiliary*) database in a BerkeleyDB JE environment. The problem is as follows:

- I am using transactions, and atomicity must span both the main and the aux DB
- therefore, as I understand the docs, I have to use a single environment (transactions cannot span several environments)
- So the two databases share one directory. But do they also share the same files?
- Because the aux DB can grow *very* big, and I want to wipe it at the start of the application.
- I have used `e.truncateDatabase(txn, name, false)` to do so
- But it appears the database directory never shrinks, so if in every application run the aux DB uses e.g. 500 MB, then after four runs, the directory is already 2 GB, irrespective of the truncation. Also I cannot see distinct files for main and aux DB

**How can I *really* wipe the aux database, so that the disk space is freed**? This is also a performance problem, because with those several GB large directories, BDB has serious trouble starting up and winding down. Can I force BDB to use separate files, so I can just delete a particular file?

---

Somehow this single environment seems at the root of the problem. For example, I would love to increase performance by giving the aux DB `setTxnNoSync()` but then this will also affect the main DB.

---

If I use `setTemporary` on the aux DB, I get a runtime exception, apparently it is disallowed to use transactions with a temporary database!?

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to open Database aux and two ore more of the following exclusive properties are true: deferredWrite, temporary, transactional

Answer (score 0):

I improved the situation a bit with the following setting:

```
envCfg.setConfigParam(EnvironmentConfig.CLEANER_MIN_FILE_UTILIZATION, "33")
```

and using `removeDatabase` instead of `truncateDatabase` upon application start. At least I don't seem to get infinite growth any longer.

I'm still interested in hearing whether I can make BDB use dedicated log files for either database.